# Creating points in QGIS from DMS coordinate CSV - partial loss of data

Tags: qgis, point, csv, import, degrees-minutes-seconds

I am inserting a csv with a list of coordinates (tab separated below)

```
y   x
8 47 7.000  -82 57 32.000
8 47 7.000  -82 57 32.000
8 47 7.000  -82 57 32.000
51 28 0.000 7 32 60.000
-35  7 0.000    138 41 60.000
-35  7 0.000    138 41 60.000
-35  7 0.000    138 41 60.000
-35  7 0.000    138 41 60.000
```

Can anyone explain why the top coordinates (8 47 7 etc.) and bottom coordinates (-35 7 0 etc.) are inserted fine, but the row in the middle (51 28 0 etc.) does not work? If I paste the middle coordinate into google maps it takes me to the correct location, as do the others.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure to line up your dms coordinates carefully, also 32 60.000 should be 33 00.000 and 41 60.000 should be 42 00.000 the below list worked for me in QGIS 3.12 (using tab between y and x, single space between d and m and between m and s:

```
y   x
  8 47 7.000    -082 57 32.000
  8 47 7.000    -082 57 32.000
  8 47 7.000    -082 57 32.000
 51 28 0.000       7 33 00.000
-35  7 0.000     138 42 00.000
-35  7 0.000     138 42 00.000
-35  7 0.000     138 42 00.000
-35  7 0.000     138 42 00.000
```

Comment: Thanks Hans. A a few questions for clarity. Not sure how the spacing ended up strange since I copied straight from the spreadsheet. In the original spreadsheet all spacing is consistent.

Why should 32 60.000 be 33 00.000?

Comment: I have "converted" my original points using hamstermap, and now it has given corrected DMS as you suggested (32 60 -> 33 00). Still don't understand why - but it worked for my large spreadsheet to correct these errors!

Comment: I have not tested if 32 60 actually gives a QGIS error, but numerically it is messy and probably the result of a rounding of 59.9999 to 3 decimals.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you just omit that point it must be a writing error.  I recommend you check the file where the coordinates are and their spacing